# TypeTest to overcome erasure with generic types in scala3

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-3

I am having problems understanding how `TypeTest`s in scala3 can replace the use of `TypeTag` in scala 2. The usecase being able to match on a generic parameter like x: List[Int].

Concrete example I am trying to solve:

```
enum Foo :
  case Bar()
  case Baz()

case class Mod[T <: Foo](modFn: T => T)

def modifyBarsOrBaz(mod: Mod[_]) = mod match
  case barMod: Mod[Foo.Bar] => ???
  case bazMod: Mod[Foo.Baz] => ???
```

the compilation results (as expected) in the comiler warning(s)

`the type test for Mod[Foo.Bar] cannot be checked at runtime` and an unreachable case.

Now my question is: is this possible to do at all in scala3?

I was under the impression that I would somehow have to provide a `TypeTest[Any, Mod[Foo.X]]` for all X which are subclasses of the `Foo` enum.

But I am struggling to even implement those tests, as well as understanding what `using` parameter the `modifyBarsOrBaz` is required for this to work.

Thus I came up with the following (not working) solution:

```
def modifyBarsOrBaz[T <: Foo](mod: Mod[T])(using TypeTest[Any, Mod[T]]) = mod match
  case barMod: Mod[Foo.Bar] => ???
  case bazMod: Mod[Foo.Baz] => ???
```

and a naive tt implementation as such

```
val tt: TypeTest[Any, Mod[Foo.Bar]] =
  new TypeTest[Any, Mod[Foo.Bar]] :
    def unapply(x: Any): Option[x.type & Mod[Foo.Bar]] = x match
      case m: Mod[_] => ??? // what to do here? use a classtag on Mod?
```

I tried to search the web for answers, but since this is pretty new I was not lucky. Any hints?

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your problem, but why do you have parameter lists for `Bar` and `Baz`? Why not have them be normal singletons?

Comment: This example is stripped down to the bare minimum. `Bar` and `Baz` are in reality product types with a couple of fields each. also, `Mod` contains the modifier function as well as metadata to ensure correct selection of what elements should be modified.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that a `TypeTest[Any, Mod[T]]` will be able to check if an `Any` is a `Mod[T]`, not to check whether or not a `Mod[T]` is a `Mod[Foo.Bar]` or a `Mod[Foo.Baz]`. What you would need are `TypeTest[Any, Mod[Foo.Bar]` and `TypeTest[Any, Mod[Foo.Baz]`:

```scala
def modifyBarsOrBaz(mod: Mod[?])(using asBar: TypeTest[Any, Mod[Foo.Bar]], asBaz: TypeTest[Any, Mod[Foo.Baz]]) =
  mod match
    case asBar(barMod) => println("barMod")
    case asBaz(bazMod) => println("bazMod")
```

I don't know why a simple `barMod: Mod[Foo.Bar]` didn't work with a `TypeTest[Any, Mod[Foo.Bar]]` in scope, I'll come to that later.

However, you now have to actually implement those `TypeTest`s yourself. Since the JVM doesn't have reification, you will have to store information about `T` in the `Mod` class. If you really want to keep `Mod` a single case class, you can do this:

```
type BarOrBaz[T <: Foo] <: String = T match {
  case Foo.Bar => "Bar"
  case Foo.Baz => "Baz"
}

case class Mod[T <: Foo](modFn: T => T, tag: BarOrBaz[T])
```

`TypeTest` instances for `Bar` and `Baz` can now be provided with an inline method:

```
import compiletime.constValue

inline given [T <: Foo]: TypeTest[Mod[?], Mod[T]] = new TypeTest:
  def unapply(mod: Mod[?]) = Option.when(mod.tag == constValue[BarOrBaz[T]])(mod.asInstanceOf[mod.type & Mod[T]])
```

`modifyBarsOrBaz` would be

```
def modifyBarsOrBaz(mod: Mod[?])(using asBar: TypeTest[Mod[Foo], Mod[Foo.Bar]], asBaz: TypeTest[Mod[Foo], Mod[Foo.Baz]]) = mod match
  case asBar(barMod) => println("barMod")
  case asBaz(bazMod) => println("bazMod")
```

For convenience, an inline `apply` method could be made:

```
object Mod:
  inline def apply[T <: Foo](modFn: T => T) = new Mod(modFn, constValue[BarOrBaz[T]])
```

And you could use it like this ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DEViwFCDRne5qCSfn0KkdQ)):

```
modifyBarsOrBaz(Mod[Foo.Bar](bar => bar))  //barMod
modifyBarsOrBaz(Mod[Foo.Baz](baz => baz))  //bazMod
```

But really, the need for type tests such as this feels like a code smell to me. I'd suggest rethinking your design to work around it rather than use tags like this.

Comment: thank you for your reply. first of all - I am open to a redesign, but I do not see another way. To explain further: `Mod` is kind of a user supplied structure which defines which elements and how the should be transformed in case of some event. Now when this event happens, I need to fetch the modifier and discriminate somehow which elements are affected (they are in different collections) and apply the transformation if appropriate.

Comment: Some questions regarding your answer:
- the `tag` would essentially be the same as a `ClassTag` no? should'nt I be using the dependency injection mechanism of classtag for this purpose?
- the `case asBar(barMod)` branches issue compile warnings the scastie - is this expected and not to be worked around?
- the `case asBar(barMod)` requires me to do a cast afterwards right? is there really no way to express `case m: Mod[Foo.Bar] => // use m typed`. I expected scala3 to be better than 2 here.
- why is inline needed here?

Comment: @winson Oh I see. You're right that the `tag` is essentially the same as `ClassTag`, so it would perhaps be better for you to just use that. I'm still not sure why there's a warning for the first branch, or why you can't directly use `case m: Mod[Foo.Bar]`, but I'm trying to look into that. It is rather unsatisfactory, honestly, so it may be better to go the Scala 2 way.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I am not conviced yet that this is a proper scala-3 idomatic solution. It seems like strictly worse than using typetag, which is removed in scala 3.